# Gmap show empty page when deploy to CHPlay

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm facing with serious problem about gmap api key (I thinks). My xamarin form app uses gmap in some of UI. I already config SHA-1 key for both debug and release mode. I work well when I generate apk file and install to my android phone. But when I public it to CHPlay then install, it always show empty map.